# Is it necessary to give my debit card details to update the macbook?

Tags: macos, apple-id, mac-appstore

when i am trying to update my version to Mac os high sierra. mac asks me to review my account in apple store. for reviewing my account i need to give my debit card details. Is it necessary to give that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is normal and necessary once Apple asks for that information on your Apple ID. When you initially sign up, this can be optional based on how precisely you establish your AppleID, but once asked, you must enter a valid form of payment to continue to use that AppleID in the stores.

You are still purchasing and agreeing to be legally bound to the license terms when you install “free” software in any of Apple’s online stores. A form of payment is a very strong anti-fraud method since there is a paper trail to get payment credentials.

Once you validate your identity, you can usually make the payment method none, use a card with low balance as suits your needs.

Comment: I have neither a debit nor a credit card. I have downloaded multiple OS updates and even paid apps (by purchasing iTunes gift cards in local stores).

Answer (score 0):

Apple provides detailed instructions for using an AppleID without a credit card here:

[Create or use an Apple ID without a payment method](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204034)

In essence, there is an option to select "None" as the Payment Type.

However, it should be possible to download updates to your current OS (including new releases) without an AppleID.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?

Comment: Can‘t speak for the downvoter but AFAIK selecting „None“ is not an option if Apple ask you to review your AppleID (neither is downloading any software from the store in that state). So your answer may not actually help the OP.